# Regex detecting global variables in PHP

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that in the example below would only match with **$session = $_POST['session'];**

```
Line #1: if (isset($_POST['session'])) {$session = $_POST['session'];}
Line #2: $session = $_POST['session'];
```

The following regex works correctly only with the second line:

**(\$.*)=.*(\$_POST.*);**

On the first line this regex does match with

```
$_POST['session'])) {$session = $_POST['session'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your regex actually had a `.*` instead of just `.`

```
(\$.*)=.(\$_POST.*);
    ^
```

`.*`s are generally pretty dangerous (in terms of over matching) since they match anything, and as much as they can. From a quick google I see that

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

So I'd advise restricting the match to at most a combination of letters, numbers and underscores (conveniently all covered by `\w`). I'd then recommend changing the second `.*` to only match characters up to the next `;` using `[^;]+` to avoid overmatching of the tail end of the expression, and also instead of using `.` to match spaces, explicitly match whitespace with `\s*`. Leaving you with:

```
(\$\w+)\s*=\s*(\$_POST[^;]+);
```

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?384im)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
(\$[^$= ]*) ?= ?(\$_POST\[[^]]*\])
```

Comment: agree this might be all OP wants, but if you remove the whitespace before the `{` in line 1 this would still match incorrectly

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks, I've edited my answer with also `$_POST` improvement.